# What is the difference between 文本 and 本文 in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

It seems both of them are referring to "text".

Can somebody give further explanations of the two similar words?

Comment: I have never seen 文本. 明鏡国語辞典・広辞苑にも載ってないようですが。。

Comment: It is not a similar one. It is like a palindrome such as 竹藪焼けた.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used "文本" in usual context in Japanese.

"文本" comes from Chinese. It pronounces "wénběn" and means text or document.
"本文" comes from Japanese. It pronounces "hon-bun" and means the contents of the text.

Both have same meanings, but have different background.

Comment: As an interesting side note, 本文 in Chinese means “this text,” just like how 本人 means “this(original) person” and 本日 means “this day” in both CN and JP. E.g. “正如本文所記載，秦篆為漢字統一之濫觴”